# Not able to load css with custom next.js and express server

Tags: reactjs, express, next.js

Refused to apply style from 'https://www.example.com/_next/2.83c6f8132fcdb15b2703.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

````
            handle(req, res);
        });


        server.get('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });```
````

Comment: perhaps you can add more information about the issue.. also, could you make sure that the css file isn't empty?

Comment: are you getting this error on localhost or on a prod env somewhere?

Comment: please provide a complete snippet of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
We were not aware that extract-css-chunks-webpack-plugin can take loaction and file name as well. We were only giving file name. So it was generating css on root which is not accessible by next by _next. 

   **Old Code**
<pre>config.plugins.push(new ExtractCssChunks({
    filename: isProduction ? '[name].[hash].css' : '[name].css',
    chunkFilename: isProduction ? '[id].[hash].css' : '[id].css',
    ignoreOrder: true
}));</pre>

**New Code After Fixing the issue**
<pre>config.plugins.push(new ExtractCssChunks({
    filename: isProduction ? 'static/css/[name].[hash].css' : 'static/css/[name].css',
    chunkFilename: isProduction ? 'static/css/[id].[hash].css' : 'static/css/[id].css',
    ignoreOrder: true
}));</pre>
```